# MySQL 8 crash after update from 8.0.? to 8.0.19

Tags: mysql

After we updated our database to 8.0.19 using `apt-get upgrade`, the server crashes at startup:

```
2020-04-11T23:11:56.970273Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
23:12:14 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7f76181d67a0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f7dfe006d50 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x562e62ba278d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x303) [0x562e61c3c553]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f838a2f4890]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(actual_key_parts(KEY const*)+0x13) [0x562e61b5f533]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(calculate_key_len(TABLE*, unsigned int, unsigned long)+0x28) [0x562e61d56ed8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_read_map(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, ha_rkey_function)+0x295) [0x562e61d57765]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(check_unique_constraint(TABLE*)+0xb0) [0x562e61ac4890]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_sj_dups_weedout(THD*, SJ_TMP_TABLE*)+0x129) [0x562e61ac4b19]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(WeedoutIterator::Read()+0xa9) [0x562e61cfdc79]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(NestedLoopIterator::Read()+0xee) [0x562e61cfe28e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(MaterializeIterator::MaterializeQueryBlock(MaterializeIterator::QueryBlock const&, unsigned long long*)+0x116) [0x562e61d03336]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(MaterializeIterator::Init()+0x287) [0x562e61d03c27]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(MaterializeIterator::MaterializeQueryBlock(MaterializeIterator::QueryBlock const&, unsigned long long*)+0x80) [0x562e61d032a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(MaterializeIterator::Init()+0x287) [0x562e61d03c27]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(AggregateIterator::Init()+0x16) [0x562e61cfdf36]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::ExecuteIteratorQuery(THD*)+0x230) [0x562e61bc47b0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::execute(THD*)+0x139) [0x562e61bc6b49]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute_inner(THD*)+0x21b) [0x562e61b57d1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x458) [0x562e61b61438]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x2811) [0x562e61b11741]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x361) [0x562e61b138f1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x127f) [0x562e61b150af]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x1c4) [0x562e61b16964]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xfbd800) [0x562e61c2d800]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x244b909) [0x562e630bb909]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7f838a2e96db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7f838851088f]
```

Following with the problematic query:

```
Query (7f76181e36e8): SELECT COUNT(*) [REDACTED]
Connection ID (thread ID): 5233
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have You submitted a bug to MySQL? Was it addressed?

Comment: Submitted: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99234
But I can't provide a repeatable test case, so we ended up by removing a feature fron our website while the issue investigated.

Comment: any luck ever since? Our team had been trying to find a build of MariaDB or MySQL which would not have "i just crashed under high-concurrency load" or "I'm having some random in-memory data-corruption" issues ever since good-old MySQL8.0... They've implemented clustering/sharding to reduce the concurrency, so it crashes/glitches only once a day on Perf-test lab, instead of doing it every ~3h, but still far from something PROD-acceptable (and yes, we don't use any fancy features - select for update, update, commit)

Comment: They updated the issue on their side
> "It turns out that your bug is a duplicate of our internal bug, that is fixed in 8.0.20. Hence, all you need to do is to upgrade."
But I don't want to crash my website again with a bad update, so I will try on another server someday